# How can I use a Pointer to structure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, fgets, gets

I have problem with pointer to structure in C.
This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10 // determine the number of students

typedef struct
{
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int gpa;
} STU;

void stuinfo(unsigned int, STU*);

int main()
{
    STU student[N];
    printf_s("The number of students is %d.\n\n", N);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        stuinfo(N, &student[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

void stuinfo(unsigned int stuinfo_n, STU* pstudent)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= stuinfo_n - 1; i++)
    {
        printf_s("Enter the first name of student %d : ", i + 1);
        fgets(pstudent->firstname, 99, stdin);
        printf_s("Enter the last name of student %d : ", i + 1);
        fgets(pstudent->lastname, 99, stdin);
    }
}
```

This program runs but does not work properly and gives an error after receiving the first input.
Output :

```
The number of students is 10.

Enter the first name of student 1 : Jason

D:\Practice\P_22\Project22\x64\Debug\Project22.exe (process 24068) exited with code -1073741819.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2022

I used gets_s() function instead of fgets() function, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: OT: Instead of `i <= N - 1` use `i < N`.

Comment: When you do `fgets(pstudent->firstname, 99, stdin)`, where does the pointer `pstudent->firstname` actually point?

Comment: Also, `stuinfo` shouldn't have a loop, since that loop is already in the `main` function. Either that (remove the loop in `stuinfo`), or remove the loop from the `main` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```c
typedef struct
{
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int gpa;
} STU;
```

`firstname` and `lastname` are pointers, but in your case they are not initialised to point to anything.

You should instead either declare them as arrays:

```c
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 64 // or something else
typedef struct
{
    char firstname[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char lastname[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int gpa;
} STU;
```

or you would need to use `malloc()` or similar to allocate memory for them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're attempting to read data into `NULL` buffers:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
```

Try allocating the buffers statically with this small change and the program should be fixed:

```
typedef struct
{
    char firstname[100];
    char lastname[100];
```

Comment: The pointers aren't `NULL`, they are pointing to *indeterminate* locations.

Comment: On my PC, the *indetermination* always *determines* `NULL` values for both.

Comment: Some systems and/or tool chains have the bad habit of setting the stack to all zeroes, particularly in debug builds. So that you won't spot your bugs until late in the release...